# File uploaded via jQuery Filer not validating

Tags: jquery, forms

Implemented jQuery.Filer in a web page form, after uploading the file when I click on submit the form throws an error that the File Upload field is empty, if I remove jQuery.Filer plugin the form works perfectly, so with the filer plugin active the form isn't detecting when a file is uploaded, can someone please help me fix this issue.

[Form Page](http://rajumenon.net/subdomains/work/virtuality/job-application-form/application.php)

```
 <input type="file" 
        name="field_5"  
        id="field_5" 
        value="" 
        class='text_box input-file' 
        onchange="fmgHandler.check_upload(this);"  
        data-validation="mime size" 
        data-validation-allowing="pdf,ppt,docx" 
        data-validation-max-size="2M" 
        data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" 
        data-show-preview="true" 
        multiple>
<label for='field_5' class='form_field'>Browse*</label>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the validation in options from jQuery.filer. For example ([further documentation](http://filer.grandesign.md/#documentation)):

```
$('input:file').filer({
    extensions: ["pdf", "ppt", "docx"],
    maxSize: 2
})
```

The `required="required"` attribute is fixed in v1.3.

Comment: Thanks! Ended up not using filer and instead implemented custom jQuery functionality.